# How can I resolve ImportError: cannot import name 'SpacyDocReader' from 'pke.readers'?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, importerror

This is my first time posting on Stackoverflow. I'm having this Import Error when trying to execute this code snippet in my jupyter notebook:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import pke
import traceback

def get_nouns_multipartite(content):
    out=[]
    try:
        extractor = pke.unsupervised.MultipartiteRank()
        extractor.load_document(input=content)
        #    not contain punctuation marks or stopwords as candidates.
        pos = {'PROPN','NOUN'}
        #pos = {'PROPN','NOUN'}
        stoplist = list(string.punctuation)
        stoplist += ['-lrb-', '-rrb-', '-lcb-', '-rcb-', '-lsb-', '-rsb-']
        stoplist += stopwords.words('english')
        extractor.candidate_selection(pos=pos, stoplist=stoplist)
        # 4. build the Multipartite graph and rank candidates using random walk,
        #    alpha controls the weight adjustment mechanism, see TopicRank for
        #    threshold/method parameters.
        extractor.candidate_weighting(alpha=1.1,
                                      threshold=0.75,
                                      method='average')
        keyphrases = extractor.get_n_best(n=15)
        

        for val in keyphrases:
            out.append(val[0])
    except:
        out = []
        traceback.print_exc()

    return out
```

And I got the error: **ImportError: cannot import name 'SpacyDocReader' from 'pke.readers'**

I tried downgrading the version of pke (to 1.8.1) but then there was KeyError 'hinglish'.

```
---> 29 get_alpha_2 = lambda l: LANGUAGE_CODE_BY_NAME[l]
     30 
     31 lang_stopwords = {get_alpha_2(l): l for l in stopwords._fileids}

KeyError: 'hinglish'
```

I have never used the pke library before so I'm very confused. I would appreciate all the support! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by downloading the latest version of pke.
I install pke (Python Keyphrase Extraction module) module from github using the following code:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/boudinfl/pke.git
```

Further, I made necessary modifications to the above code by loading the document and specifying the stoplist during the load_document function call.

Refer to https://boudinfl.github.io/pke/build/html/unsupervised.html

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import pke
import traceback

def get_nouns_multipartite(content):
    out=[]
    try:
        extractor = pke.unsupervised.MultipartiteRank()
        #    not contain punctuation marks or stopwords as candidates.
        pos = {'PROPN','NOUN'}
        #pos = {'PROPN','NOUN'}
        stoplist = list(string.punctuation)
        stoplist += ['-lrb-', '-rrb-', '-lcb-', '-rcb-', '-lsb-', '-rsb-']
        stoplist += stopwords.words('english')
        extractor.load_document(input=content,stoplist=stoplist)
        extractor.candidate_selection(pos=pos)
        # 4. build the Multipartite graph and rank candidates using random walk,
        #    alpha controls the weight adjustment mechanism, see TopicRank for
        #    threshold/method parameters.
        extractor.candidate_weighting(alpha=1.1,
                                      threshold=0.75,
                                      method='average')
        keyphrases = extractor.get_n_best(n=15)
        

        for val in keyphrases:
            out.append(val[0])
    except:
        out = []
        traceback.print_exc()

    return out
```